# while True python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, while-loop

I want this program to be in a loop until the user puts DONE

```
import datetime


fileName =input('file name :')
fileName = fileName+'.csv'
access ='w'
currentdate=datetime.date.today()

with open (fileName,access)as newFile :
    newFile.write('Name,Age,Nationality,Date\n')
    while True:
        name=input('Name:')
        age=input('Age: ' )
        nationality=input('Nationality: ')     
        newFile.write(name+','+age+','+nationality+',%s'%currentdate+'\n')
        if name or age or nationality == 'DONE':
            break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following IF statement in your code, nationality is the only variable being compared to the string value 'NONE'.

```
if name or age or nationality == 'DONE':
    break
```

Try either of the following

```
if any(x == 'DONE' for x in [name, age, nationality]):
    break

if 'DONE' in [name, age, nationality]:
    break
```

Comment: first express my gratitude  for correcting my programming path (im a beginner)

Comment: the problem is that the code is not stopping at the whim of entering DONE, it have to go on for the full loop and then its stopping , I want to break the loop at any time , can this be happen?

Comment: The keyword `break` will exit the loop. Are you sure when entering 'DONE' that it is still going through the loop?